# Grouping columns of dataframe by other dataframe and calculate weighted average of aggregated columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, weighted-average

I have a DataFrame `df1` with four time series. I want to aggregate these time-series based on the DataFrame `groups` which classifies the individual time-series into two groups. Additionally, I have a DataFrame `weights`, which defines the weighting factor (change over time) of the time-series within the groups.

What I try to get is a DataFrame `df2` which has the time-series aggregated based on the groups and weighted with the weighting factors.

This would be a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[1.2, 2.3, 0.3, 0.5], 
    '02K W':[3.5, 0.1, 'nan', 'nan'], 
    '03K W':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0], 
    '04K W':[1.5, 2.6, 8.2, 4.2]}) 

groups = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':['01K W', '02K W', '03K W', '04K W'],
    'Group':['Group1', 'Group1', 'Group2', 'Group1']}) 

weights = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    '01K W':[0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5], 
    '02K W':[0.25, 0.25, 'nan', 'nan'], 
    '03K W':[1, 1, 1, 1], 
    '04K W':[0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.5]}) 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
    'Group1':[1.85, 1.82, 6.23, 2.35], 
    'Group2':[4.2, 5.2, 2.5, 3.0]})
```

The first element in `df2` (=1.85) is calculated as:
1.2x0.5 + 3.5x0.25 + 1.5x0.25

Values of group 1: 1.2, 3.5 & 1.5 ('2021-01-01')

Weighting factors for group 1: 0.5, 0.25 & 0.25 ('2021-01-01')

Comment: It seems that you did not specify when agroup corresponds multiple rows how each item will be calculated as the aggregation of the rows matching items.

Comment: If a group corresponds to multiple rows such as "Group1", then I try to aggregate it based on the individual weights at the specific time from the Dataframe weights.

Comment: In your description the weights are related to the date dimension (i.e 'Date') not to the group rows. You should give the detail of the calculations that conducted to df2.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear. the first value in df2 1.85 is calculated as: 1.2*0.5 + 3.5*0.25 + 1.5*0.25. group 1 gets data from 3 columns which are mulitplied by 3 weights and added together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Multiply `df1` with `weights`
2. `stack` and `map` the column names to the groups
3. `groupby` "Date" and group ("level_1") and `sum`
4. `unstack` and format to the desired output

```
output = df1.set_index("Date").mul(weights.set_index("Date")).stack().reset_index(1)
output = (output.groupby([output.index, 
                          output["level_1"].map(dict(zip(groups["ID"],groups["Group"])))])
          .sum()
          .unstack()
          .droplevel(0,1)
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
          )

>>> output
            Group1  Group2
Date                      
2021-01-01   1.850     4.2
2021-01-02   1.825     5.2
2021-01-03   6.225     2.5
2021-01-04   2.350     3.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What exactly would I need to change in order to avoid the following error: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'.

Comment: Change the "nan" (strings) in your DataFrame to `np.nan` (float). Use `df1 = df1.replace("nan", np.nan)` and `weights = weights.replace("nan", np.nan)`

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, I also tried to come with a solution, you need to set the Date column as index, then the numbers of the Series of that specific row will be floats, if the series contains the data as first value, all the values will be interpreted as strings. I got that same error when trying to multiply parts of df with part of weights.